# Is there an equivalent of class number for non-fractional ideals?

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

Consider $K=\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$ with class number $h$, where $\alpha$ is a root of $f(x)=0$, and the set of primes and roots $p,r$ such that $f(r) \equiv 0 \bmod p$.
It seems there is an equivalent of class number for ideals in $\mathcal{O}_K$ of the form $<p,\alpha-r>$.

It appears that the proportion of such ideals that are principal is $1/H$, where $H$ is an integer multiple of $h$. Moreover, all ideals of norm $p^H$ are principal (see the examples below).

Does anyone know of anything in the literature that explores this topic further?

Example: consider $f(x)=x^3+91$. This gives $h=9$. Empirically, the proportion of principal ideals of the above type is $1/18$, i.e. $H=18$.
$f(r) \equiv 0 \bmod 47$ has the single root 28. $g(x)=1175x^2-24252x+27354$ has $g(28) \equiv 0 \bmod 47$, and the norm $N(g(\alpha))=47^9$, giving $N(g(\alpha)^2)=47^H$. There is no polynomial $u(x)$ with the root property of $g(x)$ but with $N(u(\alpha))=47^k$ for $k<9$.

$f(r) \equiv 0 \bmod 31$ has the three roots $7, 20, 4$. $m(x)=-84x^2-219x+844$ has $m(7) \equiv 0 \bmod 31$,  $m(20) \not\equiv 0 \bmod 31$, $m(4) \not\equiv 0 \bmod 31$, and $N(m(\alpha))=31^6$, giving $N(m(\alpha)^3)=31^H$. Similarly there is no polynomial $u(x)$ with the root properties of $m(x)$ but with $N(u(\alpha))=31^k$ for $k<6$.

The above is the simplest cubic $f(x)$ with $H \not= h$ I have been able to find. A more extreme example is $f(x)=x^3+6876x+573$, which has $h=34$, $H=13056=384h$.

Answer (score 7):

This is taken care of by Chebotarev's density theorem, or, more classically, by a theorem due to Dirichlet (proved later by Weber and Schering and others).

Take, as a simple example, the quadratic field $K = {\mathbb Q}(\sqrt{-23})$
with class number $3$. The primes of degree $1$ in $K$ that are principal in $K$ are exactly those that split in the Hilbert class field $H$, hence have
density $\frac{1}{(H:{\mathbb Q})} = \frac16$. Half of the primes are inert 
in $K$; the remaining primes, which have density $\frac13$, are equally 
distributed among the two nonprincipal ideal classes.

If you start with a quadratic number field with class number $9$, then again
the inert primes have density $\frac12$, and the rest is distributed equally among the $9$ ideal classes; in particular, the principal class contains $\frac1{18}$ of all primes.

Comment: The form of the ideals I chose excludes the inert primes, so I'm not sure I agree with your conclusions. I think I need to read up some more theory to understand your helpful answer fully. I have also added a more extreme example where H and h differ by a factor of 384.

Comment: I only covered the quadratic case. If your base field is a nonnormal cubic field, the proportion of split and inert types is completely different, of course, and also depends on the degree of the normal closure. Keywords still are the density theorems of Dirichlet, Kronecker, Dedekind, Fronebius and, ultimately, Chebotarev. For a starter, see Lenstra's and Stevenhagen's article http://www.math.leidenuniv.nl/~hwl/papers/cheb.pdf